# Why does this left outer join contain the error 'multi-part identifier could not be found'?

Tags: postgresql

I have an error mentioning 'the multi-part identifier Employee.emp_id could not be found', when hovering over Employee.emp_id. This error occurs also on other references as well, such as Transaction.amount, Transaction.emp_id, etc.

I tried this query below:

```
SELECT Employee.name, Transaction.amount
FROM Employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN Transaction
  ON (Employee.emp_id = Transaction.emp_id);
  ORDER BY Employee.name ASC;
```

The main purpose of the query was to use left outer join, to state the name from Employees table and amount from the Transaction table, and list all the names into Ascending order.

Can someone please explain this error and why it has occurred?

Answer (score 1):

you should alias your tables instead of using the table

```
SELECT E.name, T.amount
FROM Employee E
LEFT OUTER JOIN Transaction T
  ON (E.emp_id = T.emp_id);
  ORDER BY E.name ASC;
```

Comment: So the tables must not be referenced in order to access the data? Just a bit confused.

Comment: @Laura aliasing is sometimes a good practice but I don't think that's causing the error. I think you have an extra semicolon at the end of line 4.

Comment: thank you @Dan, I did not noticed the extra semicolon

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra semicolon.

```
SELECT Employee.name, Transaction.amount
FROM Employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN Transaction
  ON (Employee.emp_id = Transaction.emp_id); <-- should this be here???
  ORDER BY Employee.name ASC;
```